# Android View ID as Strings

Tags: android, json

I'm building a Class to populate my layouts using a JSON Schema. Basically in JSON I have a definition `{ type: "checkbox", label: "Label text", value: true, id: "liquids" }`. The problem is I don't just have to render the UI i also need to collect values later when the form is posted to submit it to my API service.

The ID of each element is a string when I create the View element on my layout I need to give it this id however View has `setId()` method however this can only be an integer also has to be unique.

Is there any way I can use the string as id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Strings as a form of ids by passing them to your `View`'s [`setTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) method.

Then, to find a particular `View`, use [`findViewWithTag()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object))

Just make sure that your String ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the hash code of the string as the id.

```
view.setId(string.hashCode());
```